# I'm looking for a paper from Teknikus.dk

Tags: physics, graphics-programming, graphic-effects

I'm looking for this great paper about Verlet integration: http://www.teknikus.dk/tj/gdc2001.htm

I've found this link on many websites, forums, blogs, everyone is recommending it !

The website is down for more than one week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wayback Machine](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20080704130418/http://www.teknikus.dk/tj/gdc2001.htm) to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

@The Communist Duck already posted a Wayback Machine link, but here's [another version of the article](http://www.gamasutra.com/resource_guide/20030121/jacobson_pfv.htm) that appeared on Gamasutra.

Comment: +1 for this. It's much better formatted, and is probably faster. :P

Comment: I did a quick skim and it looked identical, but didn't do a full diff, although it's from 2003 vs 2001. It's also the "printable" version of the article (instead of scattered around multiple pages).